# html canvas saveAsBmp image saved with grey-ish background?

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas, bmp

I have an OpenLayers based heat map that is populated with various heatmap layers, red yellow green gradients etc. I want to take the gradients/dots only with a white background, excluding the map totally. However when I save the bmp images I get a grey-ish background. How can I make sure I have a white background? My save code is like this -called from a button click jquery event-

```
Canvas2Image.saveAsBMP(heatLayers[currentHeat].canvas);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving the files as PNG took care of the issue.